# Device no longer connecting to wi-fi network

Tags: wi-fi

I have a Samsung Galaxy Core 2 for the past two years. it was working fine but all of a sudden the wifi in the phone is not working. Instead it shows "saved and secured" but doesn't get connected. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is switching the phone off completely so that means holding the off button down until the whole phone turns off (Reboot) Then see if it it works.  If not then go to the Wi-Fi setting on your phone and long hold on your connecting and click forget.  then click again and connect. that should work.
craigshawtech.com

Answer (score 0):

Is it a specific Wi-Fi connection that won't work, or none work? If it's a specific one, then the problem may be on the Wi-Fi router, or it's connection to the internet.

Turn the Wi-Fi router off for a few seconds and then on again,and try connecting.  Try connecting with another device.

Also, you can try removing the connection from your device and adding it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try forgetting the network and then connecting it once again. If you have recently changed your wifi password, then also this problem comes.